# QLocale Get real language name

Tags: qt, localization, translation, qlocale

I have a language code like fr_fr, fr_be.
I would like to get French and Belgium using QLocale, but I can't find how to do it.
I did:

```
QLocale locale("fr_fr"); // or fr_be
QString l = locale.languageToString(locale.language()); //returns French in both cases
```

Comment: French is a language, Belgium is a country. That is a very important distinction to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QLocale gives you the country and language names, in both native and English languages. Choose what you prefer:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QLocale>
#include <QDebug>

void displayNames(QLocale& locale)
{
    qDebug() << locale.nativeLanguageName() << locale.nativeCountryName();
    qDebug() << locale.languageToString(locale.language()) << locale.countryToString(locale.country());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "ca_ES";
    QLocale cat = QLocale("ca_ES");
    displayNames(cat);

    qDebug() << "es_ES";
    QLocale esp = QLocale("es_ES");
    displayNames(esp);
}
```

This program returns:

```
ca_ES
"català" "Espanya"
"Catalan" "Spain"
es_ES
"español de España" "España"
"Spanish" "Spain"
```

Answer (score 4):

Your are querying the language name, that is French in both cases. Maybe you want to get the country name like this:

```
QLocale locale("fr_be");
QString l = locale.countryToString(locale.country());
```

Read [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#countryToString) for more information.

Comment: It gives good results in cases like fr_fr, fr_be, France and Belgium even if I would prefer French and Belgian. But with ca_es and es_es, I get Spain for both but I would expect Catalan and Spanish.

Comment: @SteveTJS I see. The problem is that some countries like Belgium have several official languages (French, German and Dutch) but none of them is "native" for that area. Others like Spain have more than one "native" language, like Spain where they have both Catalan and Spanish. So, many times you will not have a unique binding between a country and a language. My suggestion is to use both the name of the language and the name of the country provided by the QLocale class in order to resolve any ambiguity.